Клик по иконке кластера
Как можно добавить функцию на клик по иконке кластера, которая зумить до того положения, в котором уже начинают появлятся маркеры?
Примерно вот так создаю кластер:
const clusterer = new YMapClusterer({
    method: clusterByGrid({ gridSize: 64 }),
    features: points,
    marker: feature =>
        new YMapMarker(
            {
                coordinates: feature.geometry.coordinates,
                source: 'clusterer-source',
            },
            createClusterMarkerHtmlElement(feature)
        ),
    cluster: (coordinates, features) =>
        new YMapMarker(
            {
                coordinates,
                source: 'clusterer-source',
            },
            createClusterCircleHtmlElement(features.length)
        ),
})


В голову пришла только такая реализация.
Буду рад, если кто-то предложит более лаконичный вариант
const clusterer = new YMapClusterer({
    method: clusterByGrid({ gridSize: 64 }),
    features: points,
    marker: feature =>
        new YMapMarker(
            {
                coordinates: feature.geometry.coordinates,
                source: 'clusterer-source'
            },
            createClusterMarkerHtmlElement(feature)
        ),
    cluster: (coordinates, features) => {
        const marker = new YMapMarker(
            {
                coordinates,
                source: 'clusterer-source',
            },
            createClusterCircleHtmlElement(features.length)
        )
        //@ts-ignore
        const clusterMarkerCoordinates = marker._props.coordinates

        if (marker.element) {
            marker.element.onclick = () => {
                map?.setLocation({
                    center: clusterMarkerCoordinates,
                    duration: 500,
                    zoom: map.zoom + 3,
                })
            }
        }

        return marker
    },
})

